# Show custom field of gravity form on created post and edit that custom field in Wordpress Administrator

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a serious problem. I created a form with Gravity Forms but i don't know how show custom fields on created post, and if its possible, how edit this fields in Wordpress Administrator.

Somebody can help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install the [**ACF** - advanced custom fields plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)
2. Create the custom fields you need in ACF
3. Create a form in gravity fields with the acf custom fields as custom fields.
4. You can use short codes or custom code to show the data in posts. See [ACF Documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/)

ACF provides a nice interface to edit data in admin and you can use plugins like search everything to search the custom fields data.

Comment: i'm testing... positive coming soon... or not xD

Comment: @VektorUnbreakable I trying to do the exact same thing. Did you managed to get it working? The easiest way for me would be if I could populate the ACF fields from Gravity fields. I either tried to show the ACF fields with a gravity forms html block but this does not work.

Comment: @VektorUnbreakable use a gravity form custom field block not a html block